# Point to Json File you created in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Practing my JSON to JAVA Object skills, running into an issue, trying to point to the json file i created in android studio, instead of writing out my json data in full. here is my code. Thank you

Trying to turn this:

```
 System.out.println(
            gson.fromJson("{\"draw_date\":\"2016-10-07T00:00:00.000\",\"mega_ball\":\"14\",\"multiplier\":\"02\",\"winning_numbers\":\"24 37 42 50 65\"}", MegaPOJO.class));
```

Into This:

```
 System.out.println(gson.fromJson(jsonFile, MegaPOJO.class));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this, place the json file in the raw resources folder.

I created a ResourceManager class to get the content.

```
public class ResourceManager {

    private final Context context;
    private final Resources resources;
    private static ResourceManager resourceManager;

    private ResourceManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.resources = context.getResources();
    }

    public static ResourceManager getResourceManager(Context context) {
        if (resourceManager == null) {
            resourceManager = new ResourceManager(context);
        }

        return resourceManager;
    }

    public String getJSONFromRawResources(String jsonFilename) {
        int resourceID = resources.getIdentifier(jsonFilename, "raw", context.getPackageName());

        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(resourceID);
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder jsonStringStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonStringStringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            return jsonStringStringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can access this class by:

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.getResourceManager(this);
String jsonResult = resourceManager.getJSONFromRawResources("jsonfile");
```

And then you can use:

```
 System.out.println(gson.fromJson(jsonResult, MegaPOJO.class));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you want this code to work, name the jsonfile in the /raw folder "jsonfile.json". Or change the string in the method resourceManager.getJSONFromRawResources("jsonfile");